# Java Extract multiple values from String

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

As part of a calulator program I am writing, I am required to have the user input all the parameters in one string and I need to extract the corresponding values from it.

For example the user enters "3 5 *" he'll get "15" back.

So the program I need to write will take '3' and assign that to **double input1**, '5' to **double input2**, and '*' to **char operator**.   How do I get java to assign parts of a string to different members.

I was thinking of maybe splitting the user's string into multiple strings and parsing the values out but I don't know how effective that would be.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consider the order of operations if you have more then one operation. IE (3 4 +) 3 *. A common method for this would be to use a stack. Push the values onto the stack and perform the operation on the values you pop following the operation itself. For parsing simply split on the space ' '. However if you have more complex expressions consider a post order traversal, or stack implementation.

Comment: Okay but if I did this, how do I make sure Java knows when the next value is a double or char?  Sorry I'm just starting Java, and I'm still not sure about some transitions between this and C.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

I gave a very simple breakdown in my answer here as well: [Calculating String-inputed numerical expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399539/calculating-string-inputed-numerical-expressions/23400219#23400219)

Comment: None of the answers to the first linked question are applicable here.  Neither is your answer to the second linked question.

Comment: I disagree. The user's question is on the methodology, not the procedure for his hypothesis on the methodology. General tokenization doesn't account for operator presidence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StringTokenizer to split the string wherever it finds a space.

String s = "3 5 *";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);

You can check if there are more tokens via st.hasMoreTokens().
You can use the token aka string via st.nextToken() (it returns a string).

You can also cast each "string" such as the "3" into a double via:
String firstNumString = "3";
Double first = Double.parseDouble(firstNumString);

This results in the Double variable 'first' containing the number 3.

Comment: From the `StringTokenizer` Javadoc - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code."